# Laplace transform of function of more than one random variable

Tags: probability, distributions, moment-generating-function

I have tried to be very clear and precise with this question. Please let me know if I can write it in better way or give more explanations. I don't need a solution for this problem, only opinion if my work is correct.

Assume we have for some index $i>n$ ($n \in \mathbb{N} $) the following ${\it Independent \ Random \ Variables}$ $$h_i \sim \text {i.i.d   }\ \ \mathcal{CN}(0,1)  \ \ \text{ Complex Gaussian}$$ $$\Omega_i \sim \text {i.i.d  with pdf }\ \ f_{\Omega_i}(\omega_i)$$
$$\gamma_i \in \Xi \ \ \text{ a Poisson Point Process with intensity } \lambda $$

I would like to find the ${\it Laplace}$ transform of the function $$Y=\sum\limits_{i \ >\ n} \gamma_{i}^{-1} |h_{i}|^2G(\Omega_{ i}) $$ 
where $G(.)$ is some function of $\Omega_{ i}$ (let us not go through the details of what $G$ is but assume we know it is defined from $-\infty$ to $\infty$.)
Now this look hideous at first, but this is what I tried.

**This is the way I proceed**

\begin{align*} \nonumber
\mathcal{L}(s)&= \mathbb{E}\left(e^{-s Y}\right)\\
 &=\mathbb{E}_{\{\Omega_{ i}\},\{|h_{i}|^2\}, \Xi}\Bigg[e^{-s \sum\limits_{i \ >\ n} \gamma_{i}^{-1} |h_{i}|^2G(\Omega_{ i})}\Bigg]\\\nonumber
&=\mathbb{E}_{\{\Omega_{ i}\},\{|h_{i}|^2\},\Xi}\Bigg[\prod_{i>n}\bigg(e^{-s \ \gamma_{i}^{-1}|h_{i}|^2G(\Omega_{ i}) }\bigg)\Bigg]\\\nonumber
&\stackrel{(a)}{=}\mathbb{E}_{\{\Omega_{ i}\},\Xi}\Bigg[\prod_{i>n}\mathbb{E}_{|h_{i}|^2}\bigg(e^{-s \   \gamma_{i}^{-1}|h_{i}|^2 G(\Omega_{ i}) }\bigg)\Bigg]\\\nonumber
&\stackrel{(b)}{=}\mathbb{E}_{\{\Omega_{ i}\},\Xi }\Bigg[\prod_{{i>n}}\Bigg(\frac{1}{1+s \ G(\Omega_{ i})\ \gamma_{i}^{-1} }\biggl)\Bigg]\\\nonumber
&\stackrel{(c)}{=}\mathbb{E}_{\Xi }\Bigg[\prod_{{i>n}}\mathbb{E}_{\{\Omega_{ i}\}}\Bigg(\frac{1}{1+s G(\Omega_{ i}) \gamma_{i}^{-1} }\biggl)\Bigg]\\\nonumber
&\stackrel{(d)}{=}\mathbb{E}_{\Xi }\Bigg[\prod_{{i>n}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\Bigg(\frac{1}{1+s  G(\omega_i)\gamma_{i}^{-1} }\biggl) f_{\Omega_i(\omega_i})\ d\omega_i\Bigg]\\\nonumber
&\stackrel{(e)}{=} ?????
\end{align*}

where (a) follows from the fact that the $|h_i|^2$ are independent, so the expectation of the product is the product of the expectation, (b) follows from the moment generating function of an exponential random variable because $h_i$ is Gaussian so $|h_i|^2$ is exponential; (c)same reasoning as (a) but for $\Omega_i$;(d)from the taking the expectation of a function of the random variable $\Omega_i$.

My questions are:

1- Do you agree with the steps above ?

Next I would like to utilize the probability generating function for the Poisson Point Process to continue part (e)

The formula is stated next, let $\Phi$ be a Poisson Point Process with intensity $\lambda$. Then

$$\mathbb{E}\left( \prod_{x\in \Phi} v(x)\right)= \text{exp} \left(-\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} [1-v(x)]\lambda dx\right)$$

2- How can I use this theorem to continue step (c)? any thoughts?