# Finding the best predictor Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation, brownian-motion

I want to find the best predictor of $(B_3-B_2)(B_4-B_{\pi})$ given an observation of $B_1$

Where $B_t$ is brownian motion for time $t \geq 0$.

I am not sure how to approach this.

I know it will be the result of the conditional expecation: $\mathbb{E}[(B_3-B_2)(B_4-B_{\pi})|B_1]$ But have no idea how to compute this result.

Would $(B_3-B_2)$ be independent of $(B_4-B_\pi)$ ?

I know the property of an independence of increments in brownian motion exists, but was not sure if that could be applied here.

Comment: The last line answers the question on the penultimate line.

Comment: So you are saying it is okay to say:

$$\mathbb{E}[(B_3-B_2)(B_4-B_{\pi})|B_1] =$$
$$\mathbb{E}[(B_3-B_2)|B_1] + \mathbb{E}[(B_4-B_{\pi}) | B_1] = 0$$ ?

Comment: No, I haven't said anything like that!  Your last statement asserts non-overlapping increments are independent.  The penultimate one involves non-overlapping increments, whence they must be independent. But the expectation of a product of (conditionally) independent variables is *not* the sum of the expectations. Examples of the correct formula can be found by [searching our site](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=expectation+independent+product).

Comment: Hmm. I searched the first page, and did not find anything relevant.

I tried another attempt, at the problem, however:

$$\mathbb{E}[(B_3-B_2)(B_4-B_\pi)|B_1] = \mathbb{E}(B_3-B_2)(B_4-B_\pi)$$ since independence implies $Cov((B_3-B_2)(B_4-B_\pi),B_1) = 0$

Is this a step in the right direction?
Thanks for your help so far @whuber

Comment: From the first page of hits: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/129372/covariance-of-the-empirical-distribution-function, http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/52699/919, http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134242, http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/28231/919, etc., etc. all cite and use a formula for expectations of products of independent random variables.

Comment: hm, as you can probably tell I do not have a strong background In mathematics. I am failing to see how the links you have provided are relevant to conditional expectation between independent variables.

I think however, $Cov(X,Y) = E(XY) - E(X)E(Y)$ might be what you are hinting at, when $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Everything else looks like it is written in Hebrew :/